# Does SSRS have a cache

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am not trusting SSRS when it renders.  I feel like it's caching at times and the results are not updated.  Is there some cache I need to worry about to force clear when I'm not sure?

I noticed if I run an ssrs report right after changing a proc, and then run it a few minutes later I get different results.  It's almost like there is a delay from when I change a proc to when it finally results in ssrs showing the new data for the proc changes.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're seeing this behavior in BIDS or when viewing a report online via Report Manager (or custom app)?

Answer (score 0):

It definitley has, but I think you need to configure the caching explicitly (Report Manager, report properties, Processing Options). See the [Caching Reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) section on MSDN.
There might be some other caching options used internally when exporting a report, but this is not your case.

Maybe the browser is caching data as well. Try deleting the browser cache and re-run the report.